# .net google calendar api : anybody can create/update/delete events

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

In my application, i am using google calendar api.
i have created client id and client secret for my account as well as for few users.
when i run the application, if i am not logged in to the browser it ask me login to my gmail account. once i log in to my gmail account, i can successfully get/create/update/delete events on my calendar.

currently i am loggedin with my calendar id to gmail account, i am able to get the events for different calendar id but the is i am not able to create/update/delete events by another user calendar id.

my requirement is, i am logged in to my gmail id lets say abc@gmail.com and i am able to fetch events for calendar  id xyz@gmail.com but not able to  create/update/delete events for calendar id xyz@gmail.com

i did lot of research on internet but did not find anything. as per my knowledge we need to pass authorization + access token to the request. i tried this also but did not work.

Please suggest what should i do to achieve this requirement.

```
calID = Convert.ToString(Session["CalenderId"]);
        userSecret = Convert.ToString(Session["UserSecret"]);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(calID) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userSecret))
        {
            using (var stream =
                new FileStream(userSecret, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json/" + calID);

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                // Response.Write("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Google Calendar API service.
            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,

            });
```

Hope you have understood my requirement. waiting for earliest response.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember that authentication is on a per user basses.   when you run GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync and save "user" loging in with abc@google.com you can access abc@googles.com's calendar.

When you login again using GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync and save "User2" using xyz@google.com you have access to xyz@google.com's calendar.

What you should do is have xyz@google.com share their calendar with abc@google.com then they will have access to update it.

**Untested sample code:**

```
AclRule body;
body.Role = "writer";
body.Scope.Type = "user";
body.Scope.Value = "abc@gmail.com";
service.Acl.Insert(body, calendarId).Execute();
```

Comment: Can you please tell how should i share calendar id or can you give me link of working example

Comment: I don't have an example off hand but https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl/insert#auth   Note: scope is the users email address you want to share your calendar with.

Comment: ripped some code for you out of my sample project I didn't test it though it should be close.

Comment: after i share my calendar with another calendar, its working for only shared calendar but getting exception 404 not found error for unshared calendars to fetch the events... do you have any idea why it is happening so? please reply